# sent values to others activity

Tags: android, gps, ioio

i need some helps

1. to get gps value (longitude, latitude, and altitude) on GPS_thread activity and send this value to others acritivity (MapsFragment activity and LoggingData activity)
2. send sensor value (from IOIO microcontroller) from Sensor_thread and send this value to others activity too (SensorFragment activity and

hope someone can help me, because i still beginner for programming on java and just have a little basic java programming

thank you so much

this is the code for GPS_thread

```
package com.androidgassensor;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPS_thread extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPS_thread(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }


    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPS_thread.this);
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

and this is the code for Sensor_thread activity

```
package com.androidgassensor;

import ioio.lib.api.AnalogInput;
import ioio.lib.api.exception.ConnectionLostException;
import ioio.lib.util.BaseIOIOLooper;
import ioio.lib.util.IOIOLooper;
import ioio.lib.util.android.IOIOActivity;

public class Sensor_thread extends IOIOActivity{

    float vgas;
    float vTemp;

    class Looper extends BaseIOIOLooper {

        private AnalogInput CO_,Temp_;

        public void setup() throws ConnectionLostException {
            CO_ = ioio_.openAnalogInput(34);
            Temp_ = ioio_.openAnalogInput(35);
            }

        public void loop() throws ConnectionLostException {

            try {
                vgas = CO_.getVoltage();
                vTemp = Temp_.getVoltage();
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }

            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                ioio_.disconnect();
            } catch (ConnectionLostException e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        protected IOIOLooper createIOIOLooper() {
            return new Looper();
        }
    }


    public float getvgas(){
        return vgas;
    }

    public float getvTemp(){
        return vTemp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Could you show what you've tried to do, so we can fix it and suggest improvements?  Thanks!

Comment: I made a video tutorial that demonstrates how to pass data between activities: http://youtu.be/azvVTJQpLmc

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to insert value

```
Intent it = new Intent(this, DetailedReport.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putDouble("GPS", value);
```

and fetch it using

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      Double gps = extras.getDouble("GPS");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: wahhh thank you very much for your response, actually i got an answer from my friend, and he said to use volatile syntaxt, it can be save the value what did i want and can be send to others thread

but now, i have anothers problem with the inflater